# move a pattern to the beginning of a line with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

how can i move a pattern to the beginning of the line?

```
1702,1833,09C4,098C:325F|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige
```

should be

```
325F:1702,1833,09C4,098C|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige
```

i figured out that i can insert a char or a word to the beginning when my pattern is found. but i don't get it to move my searched pattern...

```
sed -r '/(:325F)/ s/^/#/'
```

this puts a "#" to the beginning when my pattern ":325F" is found.

when i do this: `sed -r '/(:325F)/ s/^/\1/'` it gives me an error...
has anyone some tips to get me in the right direction?

br
chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You directly use find and replace in sed.

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^|]*\)/\2:\1/' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '1702,1833,09C4,098C:325F|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige' | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^|]*\)/\2:\1/'
325F:1702,1833,09C4,098C|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige
$ echo '1702,1833,09C4,098C:325F|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige' | sed 's/^\([^:]*\):325F/325F:\1/'
325F:1702,1833,09C4,098C|Sky|sportdigital|TV|Sky sonstige
```

Comment: nice1, this works like a charm. ty very much. i will now examine this regex.

Comment: @ChrisvanZet Welcome to stackoverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)